# Paypal parallel payment using saved card

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I am saving the customer credit/debit card on paypal. is there is any method to send **Parallel** Payment using these saved cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your looking to use pay-pal vault with adaptive payments APIs? I was stuck with the same sort of issue.

My research concluded that this cannot be done, with the current adaptive payments APIs.

So there are two solutions

1) Wait till the rest api team adds spilt payments to the rest APIs. You can follow development of this feature @ https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/9

2) Pay into one account (A nominee account look it up) and use mass payments to pay out to other accounts